# Почему курсор во время перетаскивания имеет вид not-allowed?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Реализована небольшая библиотека по перетаскиванию элементов в блоке (сам проект на vue).
Перетаскивание работает, но, при этом, курсор во время переноса элемента принимает вид как будто это невозможно (not-allowed). 
Не могу разобраться почему.

На событие dragStart добавляла `event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';`
и на dragOver `event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';`
Но изменений никаких не последовало.
Повторяется на Win10 во всех браузерах, на линуксе вроде нет такого.

Может кто сталкивался или знает куда копать.
[image: перетаскивание]

Comment: Частично вопрос решен. Нужно было на событие dragOver добавить event.preventDefault(); Т.к. браузер показывает подобный курсор на элементах, которые обычно нельзя перетаскивать.

Comment: Теперь, если курсор наведен на блочки с картинками, то курсор отображается как нужно. Но вот если он в зоне обертки (белый фон), то всё равно not-allowed

Comment: Событие dragOver поставьте на весь контейнер (белый фон).

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko точно) Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для элементов, которые обычно нельзя перетаскивать, нужно сбрасывать дефолтное поведение (event.preventDefault()) на событии dragOver.